# MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 does not support multiple keyboard collaboration

Tags: keyboard, mojave

**OS**: Mojave 10.14.6

**Laptop**: MacPro 2017

**Problem**:
Looks like I can't use two keyboards to execute the same command collaboratively. E.g: For typing `command + space`, it perfectly works if I execute this shortcut only on one keyboard. However, if I press `command` at one keyboard, and space at another, the laptop can only recognize the space.

**Keyboard combinations I've tried**:

- Apple a1314 + Mac built-in keyboard
- Apple a1644 (with wire and when it's wireless) + Mac built-in keyboard
- Apple a1314 + Apple a1644

None of them can work with each other.

Any solution to the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK problem solved. After installing [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html) (originally to solve the caps lock delay), I found I can work on two keyboards at the same time. The version I installed was 11.6.0.